# How to get iPhones angle from Horizon?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-motion, cmmotionmanager

I am currently working on an AR tracker for iOS. I have the horizontal tracking working fine but have run into an issue tracking the object vertically. When I get the devices orientation using CMMotionManager it gives me a value of 0 (Straight Up), 90 (Straight Ahead), and 0 (Straight Down). This does not do what I need it to do to be able to tell the devices angle compared to the horizon. Currently I get the pitch of the attitude from the motion manager.

```
motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: queue, withHandler: { [weak self] (motion, error) -> Void in
    if let attitude = motion?.attitude {
        self?.pitch = attitude.pitch * 180.0/Double.pi

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        }
    }

})
```

What would be the best way to get the devices angle from the horizon (ie. straight forward is 0, straight down is -90, and straight up is 90.